Sqlalchemy not respecting logging level
I configure my sqlalchemy logging:
alchemy_logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.myengine')
alchemy_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s | %(asctime)s | %(name)s | %(message)s")
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
alchemy_logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

url_object = URL.create(
    "postgresql+psycopg2",
    ...
)

engine = create_engine(url_object, logging_name="myengine", echo=True)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    query = "SELECT 'Hello'"
    conn.execute(text(query))

I expect my logs to be in DEBUG level, but in output I see this:
INFO | 2024-12-06 15:58:11,303 | sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.myengine | select pg_catalog.version()
INFO | 2024-12-06 15:58:11,303 | sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.myengine | [raw sql] {}
INFO | 2024-12-06 15:58:11,305 | sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.myengine | select current_schema()
INFO | 2024-12-06 15:58:11,305 | sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.myengine | [raw sql] {}
INFO | 2024-12-06 15:58:11,306 | sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.myengine | show standard_conforming_strings
INFO | 2024-12-06 15:58:11,306 | sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.myengine | [raw sql] {}
INFO | 2024-12-06 15:58:11,307 | sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.myengine | BEGIN (implicit)
INFO | 2024-12-06 15:58:11,307 | sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.myengine | SELECT 'Hello'
INFO | 2024-12-06 15:58:11,307 | sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.myengine | [generated in 0.00010s] {}
<sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.CursorResult object at 0x110a60ec0>
INFO | 2024-12-06 15:58:11,308 | sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.myengine | ROLLBACK

What's my problem? Is there a way to set the correct level?

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/faq/connections.html#how-do-i-configure-logging
